# For loop with flexible stop variable

Tags: ruby

I need to write a loop

```
for x in (1..y)
```

where the `y` variable can be changed somehow. How can I do that?

For example:

```
for x in (1..y/x)
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Can you tell us about the use case for this? This won't work because x is only defined in the loop, so you can't use x to define when it stops and it doesn't look like y is defined here. In most cases with Ruby, there are better ways to loop through a collection.

Comment: You'd have to surround the `y/x` in parens for it to work there.

Comment: You might consider doing it like so (for example): `y = 10; x = 1; while x < y; puts x; y -= x; x += 1; end` prints `1,2,3`. btw, `for` is rarely used. I've never used it.

Comment: Note, it's not idiomatic to use `for` loops in Ruby. A `for` loop leaks its intermediate variable into the global variable space, which is *sometimes* useful, but usually not something we want to do. Instead, we use `each` or `times` or `upto` or an iterator to loop over an array or a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we'd use a `loop do` with a guard clause:

```
x = 1
loop do
  break if x >= y
  x += 1
  ...
end
```

Make sure `y` is larger than `x` or it'll never do anything. `y` can change if necessary and as long as it's greater than `x` the loop will continue. As soon as `y` drops below `x` the loop will terminate on the next iteration.

*Note:* I use `>=` because testing for equality is a bug-in-waiting. Sometimes we try to compare where `x` starts out greater than `y` or we are incrementing a float and comparing it to an integer or another float and using `==` and never hit the magic "equal" causing the loop to run away. Instead always check for a greater-than-or-equal to end the loop.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be confused about return values. This actually works fine, it's just that the return value is equal to the original range.

```
y = 4
for x in (1..y)
  puts x
end
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
#=> 1..4
```

Here's a [code snippet to prove it](https://repl.it/tg4).

Comment: No, since it's optional.

Comment: ...and has nothing to do with a changing `y`.